# Donde está java en zulu 9?

Tags: java, azul-zulu

Descargué la [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) zulu en su versión `9` pero no encuentro el programa java por ningún lado (y así no puedo usar esa vm con el netbeans IDE).

¿Alguna sugerencia de como hallarlo o complementar ese ambiente para poder correr programas?

### Actualización

Descargué zulu de nuevo y esta vez si se descomprimió el `java.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las versiones anticipadas de Zulu 9 están disponibles para Windows, Mac y Linux desde la página Zulu.org.  Por favor, seguir el enlace http://zulu.org/zulu-9-pre-release-downloads/ para bajar los archivos más recientes.

Tras bajar un archivo con la nomenclatura zulu9.0.0.x-ea-jdk9.0.0-$PLATFORM a su ordenador, extraer el contenido zip a su $PLATFORM.  El programa "java" se encontrará en la carpeta llamada  /zulu9.0.0.x-ea-jdk9.0.0-$PLATFORM/bin.

Será necesário indicar ruta completa de la carpeta  /zulu9.0.0.x-ea-jdk9.0.0-$PLATFORM/bin al PATH y seleccionar la carpeta /zulu9.0.0.x-ea-jdk9.0.0-$PLATFORM como ruta del entorno variable JAVA_HOME.

Agradecería que nos confirmaras si el IDE consigue cargar Zulu 9 correctamente.

Un saludo.

--Mateo

Comment: Gracias, la bajaré de nuevo, no sé por qué no aparecía java.exe en la carpeta bin, de momento lo que había hecho era suplirle el java.exe por el del sun jdk.

Comment: A pesar de algunos errores consigue cargar, por estar algo fuera del tema del sitio subiré los resultados en http://javamexico.org/ como un review para la comunidad hispana para dos versiones de netbeans y de windows. Saludos y muchas gracias por su amable ayuda. Vuestro nivel de castellano me sorprendió.